# where('expired_at','>', Carbon::today() ) returns blance []

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'd like to get `coupon` data validated by `expired_at` columun. I coded as following. It should have returned one instance, but it returns blance `[]`.

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$coupon = $currentUser
    ->coupons
    ->where('expired_at', '>' ,$today);
```

As the following shows, $currentUser has coupon which 'expired_at' is later than `$today`. Could you tell me why I cannot get the data?

```
>>> $coupons = $currentUser->coupons
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#804
     all: [
       App\Coupon {#741
         id: 8,
         created_at: "2016-04-28 22:20:48",
         updated_at: "2016-05-02 17:10:04",
         is_used_flg: 0,
         expired_at: "2016-07-31 00:00:00",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#789
           user_id: 2,
           coupon_id: 8,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

The following is coupon model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coupon extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('amount', 'validate_period', 'is_activated_flg', 'expired_at');

    public function  users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function  match()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Match');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use whereBetween of laravel

Comment: You could always use Carbon to generate a proper date for today with `$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now();`

Comment: Sorry, to tell the truth, I've used Carbon

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing date as date format as below.

```
$today = date("2016-04-28 22:20:48");
$coupon = $currentUser
    ->coupons
    ->where('expired_at', '>' ,$today);
```

Comment: @toshikaseda, above solution is working for me. So try it with your code.

Comment: What is the datatype of "expired_at" field? Is it datetime or something else?

Comment: It is datetime. `expired_at: "2016-07-31 00:00:00"` .

Comment: I've solved. I should have added `()` like `coupons()`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you use $today = Carbon::today(); the

```
 $today = Carbon {#897 ▼
  +"date": "2016-05-02 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
}
```

then you will get error.
so use below code

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
$coupon = $currentUser
    ->coupons
    ->where('expired_at', '>' ,$today)->get();
```

Comment: Not go well.
It return the following.
>>> $user->coupons->where('created_at', '>', $today)->get()
PHP warning:  Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in /Users/toshihirokaseda/Laravel/Labrador/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ExecutionLoop/Loop.php(79) : eval()'d code on line 1 and defined in /Users/toshihirokaseda/Laravel/Labrador/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 324

Comment: $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    $coupon = $currentUser
        ->coupons
        ->where('expired_at', '>' ,$today)->get();  Are you using get() in ending

Comment: Yes, I used get() in ending.

Comment: I've solved. I should have added `()` like `coupons()`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. I should have added `()` like `coupons()` .

```
today = Carbon::today();
$coupon = $currentUser
    ->coupons()
    ->where('expired_at', '>' ,$today);
```